Which is correct “Number is “or “number’s”
I want to know if this sentence is correct:

What number’s this?

I would like to know if it's OK to use short form? Or should I use

What number is this?


Welcome to EL&U.SE! While your question is about English, and also clear and understandable, it may not be suitable for this site. I would suggest English languae Learners (ELL).SE.

Apparently, this question is suitable for the present site; see this related question.

We might say "What number’s this?” but not write it. It can mean too many things. People say things imperfectly, while writing carries the expectation of more thought. I would not recommend the apostrophe version as a good model.

Thanks for the reply. Your comment do help me a lot.

I guess nobody agree with me that this should be migrated, then. In that case, I'll answer it here.

@LukeL Since LPH's link provides an answer that answer this question, I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of the other. The answer there is that the contracted form can be used anywhere except at the end of a clause, so Brown Donald APM's sample sentence is fine.

People are closing questions on this site in an incredibly sloppy manner. This question is a duplicate of this one, but it's not a duplicate of the one it was closed for being a duplicate of.

What's incorrect about that sentence is not contracting number is to number's, but the place in the sentence that you're doing it. For example, his hat's really weird sounds fine to me, but whose hat's this sounds off to me. It's a good question with what I think is an interesting answer, but it's been lost to the mad stampede to close questions on this site.

Basically, using short form, i.e., replacing is with 's, is a commonly-used, but informal way of writing it. Common examples are "it's", meaning "it is", "that's", meaning "that is", and many, many more. While pronouns are more common, we can also use "noun + 's" for "noun is". A common example is "that dog's running like crazy" or "that bird's very beautiful". Your case is a bit unusual, though, since we do not often see "number's". But according to the rule, it is in fact valid, albeit being slightly a little weird. Keep in mind though, all shortened forms are informal, and more commonly used in speech and casual conversations (because when we speak, the difference in pronunciation is minimal), than in written text. In some contexts, you can still use abbreviated form in written text (for example, on SE using abbreviated words and phrases are perfectly OK as long as everyone knows what you mean).

It's not weird at all.

@phoog: No, the original sentence is indeed a little weird, but not for the reason this answer gives. See my comment on the question itself.
